# Did Americans leave behind over $1bn in tax refunds in 2012?

Tags: united-states, advertising, taxes

In [this television advertisement](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F3tlVzjcQiA) H&R Block claims that:

> Last year, thinking they could do their own taxes, Americans left behind more than a billion dollars.

Did American tax payers leave behind over $1 billion in tax refunds in 2012 (the last tax year)?

Comment: Assuming 50 million people did their own taxes, this amounts to only $20 apiece.

Comment: I kind of hope the answer will include that [tax practitioners may be more aggressive](http://www.aaajournals.org/doi/abs/10.2308/acch.2007.21.4.411) than their clients desire and that the cost of a tax practitioner may outweigh the increased tax return.

Comment: Note that the same commercials say that only H&R BLock only finds more money for 1 in 5 people.  Unless the population of people who go to H&R Block is WAY better at that kind of thing than people who don't, I think that data means that most people doing their own taxes are doing a fine job of it, or at least that the number of people who ought to go to H&R Block, and aren't, is relatively small.